# What's the grammar of "What was it you said?"?

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure, appositives

"Zootopia" around 00:40:49/01:48:32

> Scene 17: Running the Plate
>
> *[Judy and Nick leave the Oasis; Nick turns to Judy, straightening his tie]*
>
> Nick Wilde: Well, I had a ball. You are welcome for the clue, and seeing as how any moron can run a plate, I will take that pen and bid you adieu. *[holds out his hand for the pen]*
>
> Judy Hopps: The plate. I can't run a plate. Ooh... I'm not in the system yet.
>
> Nick Wilde: *[impatient]* Give me the pen, please...
>
> Judy Hopps: *[turns to Nick, smiling slyly]* **What was it you said?** "Any *moron* can run a plate"? Gosh, if only there were a moron around who were up to the task.

(http://zootopia.wikia.com/wiki/Zootopia/Transcript)

Is "**you said**" the (by the way, should I use "an" instead of "the"?) appositive clause of "**it**"?

Or is "**it**" introductory and "**you said**" the logical subject?

How about "What was it *what* you said?"?

Answer (score 4):

> *What was it you said?*

It's tricky!

This is an *it*-cleft construction where the foregrounded element is questioned. "It" is the subject of the matrix *be* clause, with the relative clause appearing in extranuclear position at the end.

"It" is just a place-holder for the variable, which is defined in the relative clause, though the latter is not syntactically part of the subject.

Comment: Interestingly enough, the words can be rearranged to: "You said what?" which has roughly the same meaning, although not quite the same nuance.

Comment: And I think there's an implicit "that", or at least a "that" could be included: "What was it that you said?"

Answer (score 3):

Technically, "*a noun clause*" can't refer to "*a pronoun*". So, we can't say that there is a bridge between the pronoun "*it*" and "*you said*".

I think that there is an omitted "*that*" there.

> What was it **that you said**?

You can use "that" in this way.

> What do you like **that I don't like**?
>
> What do you know **that I should know**?

Comment: "What do you like that I don't like?" "What do you know that I should know?" Both of the two that-clauses are relative clauses of "what", am I right?

Answer (score 3):

Compare:

> That is all the money he has.

**he has** is a restrictive clause defining **the money**.

> That is all the money *he has in the world*.     [his "net worth"]
>
> That is all the money *he has with him at the moment*. [on his person now]

Answer (score 2):

The "missing relativiser" is *What was it **that** you said?*. For most contexts this would be *exactly* equivalent to *What **did** you say?* - but in this specific "rhetorical question" context the longer version is probably more suitable. The shorter one is commonly used as a genuine request for something to be repeated (because the speaker didn't hear, or has forgotten), but there's no suggestion of that here. It's just sarcasm.

<sub>*{transcribed from an earlier comment}*</sub>

Comment: ***What was it you said**, something about pigs flying?*  can be a request for something to be repeated verbatim.